# Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 9 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, sasl

In our company we are trying to setup 3node Kafka cluster with SSL encryption and SASL/Kerberos authentication. Below is what I have done.

broker1, broker2, broker3 are my hostnames for 3 kafka servers and "kerberosServer" is the hostname of kerberos server.

I have created 3 principles on  kerberosServer which are kafka/broker1@EXAMPLE.COM, kafka/broker2@EXAMPLE.COM, kafka/broker3@EXAMPLE.COM and created a keytab called kafka-server.keytab and added all the above 3 principles to the kafka-server.keytab

I am able to bring up the kafka cluster. But when I am trying to produce some messages from kafka client i am getting below error:

ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 6 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)

I am using kerberos server as the kafka client and I created a new keytab for client called kafka_client.keytab and added a new principle called kafka-client/kerberosServer@EXAMPLE.COM. and below is my client details:

client-sasl.properties file:

```
    security.protocol=SASL_SSL

    sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
    ssl.truststore.location=/opt/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password=affirmed
```

kafka_client_jaas.conf:

```
KafkaClient {
     com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true
      useKeyTab=true
      storeKey=true
      keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_client.keytab"
      principal="kafka-client/kerberosServer@EXAMPLE.COM";

};
```

when I am producing using below command I am getting the error

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list broker1:9094,broker2:9094,broker3:9094 --topic test --producer.config ../config/client-sasl.properties
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /etc/security/keytabs/kafka_client.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is kafka-client/kerberosServer@EXAMPLE.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is kafka-client/kerberosServer@EXAMPLE.COM
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded

sasllll
[2018-04-24 17:41:49,214] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 7 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

Comment: Are you sure the broker ports are 9094 and not 6667? I think if you set up with Ambari then it's 6667.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am using 9094. Below is my server.properties file for 3 brokers.

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093,SASL_SSL://:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://broker1:9092,SSL://broker1:9093,SASL_SSL://broker1:9094

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093,SASL_SSL://:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://broker2:9092,SSL://broker2:9093,SASL_SSL://broker2:9094

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093,SASL_SSL://:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://broker3:9092,SSL://broker3:9093,SASL_SSL://broker3:9094

Comment: Do you see anything in the Kafka logs?

Comment: Yes, I have seen kafka logs and couldnt find anything there.